# AWS Active MQ: how to set TTL when queue created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mq

Is it possible to set TTL for AWS ActiveMQ queue in c# ?
I need this way in my c# app because user cannot have permissions to change AWS ActiveMQ Queues but the app should do it.
So, how it can be done?